# Common onChange event fails for Select control

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have created a common useForm.tsx file for handling onChange event. However, for the select control onChange, I get the below error.

Any idea how can I fix this?

*Error:*

```
Type '(e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: SelectChangeEvent<string>, child: ReactNode) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'SelectChangeEvent<string>' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>'.
      Type 'Event & { target: { value: string; name: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>': nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persistts(2322)
Select.tsx(19, 3): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
```

*useForm.tsx code:*

```
 import { ChangeEvent, useState } from 'react';

 interface FormFieldInitialValues {
   [key: string]: string;
 }

 const useForm = (formFieldInitialValues: FormFieldInitialValues) => {
   const [values, setValues] = useState<FormFieldInitialValues>(
   formFieldInitialValues
 );

 const handleInputChange = (
   e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>
 ) => {
   const { name, value } = e.target;
   setValues({
     ...values,
     [name]: value,
   });
 };

  return {
   values,
   setValues,
   handleInputChange,
  };
 };

export default useForm;
```

*My Select control code:*

```
<Controls.Select
   name="classSelect"
   label="Class"
   value={values.classSelect}
   onChange={handleInputChange}   -> shows an error here
   options={GetClassesService()}
></Controls.Select>
```

However, the same code works fine with Input control.

```
 <Controls.Input
   name="lastName"
   label="Last Name"
   value={values.lastName}
   onChange={handleInputChange}
 />
```

appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you are using mui and that their `event` object does not have the same type as the standard React event.
the error tells you that

> Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible. Type 'SelectChangeEvent' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLSelectElement>'.

```js
import { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material";
//...
const handleInputChange = (
   e: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>
 ) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target; // you may need a cast here
  setValues({
    ...values,
    [name]: value,
  });
};
```

Comment: onChange={handleInputChange as (event: SelectChangeEvent<string>, child: React.ReactNode) => void} in the select control worked for me.